# Flex 3: getting .length of custom component id within a repeater... works sometimes, but not all the time

Tags: apache-flex, repeater

I have a repeater that populates a component, called 'project'.  The project components are given an ID of 'wholeProject'.  In all of my functions up until now, I was able to determine how many project components were made by doing the following:

```
wholeProject.length;
```

I used this in for loops, for each loops, and for changing the item settings within a project, i.e. something like this:

```
wholeProject[i].studentName = "Billy Bob";
```

However, I'm creating a new function that does not seem to like this wholeProject.length reference.  I'm using it within the same level as all the others (i.e. the parent level).  So far, my function is simply this:

```
public function getStudentYears():void
{
    Alert.show(String(wholeProject.length));
}
```

when the application loads, the alert message simply does not appear.  If I change the alert to something like this:

```
Alert.show("This is just a test.");
```

it works just fine.  But for some reason, the wholeProject.length doesn't work in this function whereas it does in all my other ones.  Anybody have any ideas as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your repeater's data provider length instead.

Comment: But what about when i need to reference or edit a piece of the component, i.e. - studentName

Comment: Also, I get "Access of undefined property ***repeaterID***." when i change the alert message to: Alert.show(String(repeaterID.dataProvider.length));

Comment: Try to make it independent and data-driven. So just change data and component reflects changes.

Comment: it's far too deep into the project to make that change... I just don't understand why wholeProject.length works in some functions, but not others.